# Примеры сверточных нейронных сетей

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Где можно найти полноценные примеры сверточных нейронных сетей для C# без применения сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь описаны свёрточные сети, есть ссылки на примеры.](http://ru.datasides.com/code/cnn-convolutional-neural-networks/)